# Mongoose: findByIdAndUpdate: Trying to update all documents with name field (firstName + lastName)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the documents with the new field name which needs to be combination of firstName and lastName from the same document. I have written a snippet here and trying to update values in the database. It's not getting updated, there are no errors. I have tried to cast _id to ObjectId, But it didn't work.

MongoDB: 3.4
Mongoose: 4.11.x

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('./models/user')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})

const users = User.find({}, function(error, doc){
    doc.forEach(function(raw_doc){
        if(raw_doc.firstName) {
            firstName = raw_doc.firstName
        }else{
            firstName = ''
        }
        if(raw_doc.lastName) {
            lastName = raw_doc.lastName
        }else{
            lastName = ''
        }
        name = firstName + " " + lastName
        const user_update = User.findByIdAndUpdate(raw_doc._id, { name: name }, function(error, res) {
            if (error){
                console.log(error)
            }else{
                console.log(res)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what did you get any error or how did you say not able to update DB, are you saying from `console.log(res)` ?

Comment: I am simply running this code, It should update the entries in db right? but it's not doing it.

Comment: what did you get here : `console.log(res)` ?

Comment: getting the documents back with no change. I have set ```{new:true}``` but it is not updating the value of ```name``` field. I have cross-checked in the database, But the field is not updated.

Comment: Is this one time operation ? your mongoDB version ?

Comment: Yes. this is one time operation only. MongoDB 3.4, Mongoose 4.11.x

Comment: I have a feeling the issue is coming from the foreach loop. You might need to use some form of asynchronous programming to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
async function dBConnection() {

    try {
        let dbOp = await Users.find({}).lean(true);
        if (dbOp.length) {
            for (const i of dbOp) {
               const firstName = (i.firstName && (i.firstName).length) ? i.firstName : '';
               const lastName = (i.lastName && (i.lastName).length) ? i.lastName : '';
               const name = firstName + " " + lastName;
               const resp = await Users.findByIdAndUpdate(i._id, { name: name }, { new: true })
                console.log(i._id, '::', resp)
            }
            db.close()
        } else {
            console.log('No users found')
            db.close()
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in DB Op ::', error);
        db.close()
    }
}

module.exports = dBConnection();
```

Comment: I found the solution and it is working, is good to answer my own question? I haven't  kept the name field in User schema.

Comment: @Viraj : Yes schemas do restrict unknown field :-) It's an user mistake you can delete this post rather than someone voting to delete it :-)

Comment: Really deleting it would be an only option? Don't want to do any unfair with your's and @richard-lovell 's helping effort.

Comment: @Viraj : Just suggested as someone might raise a flag to delete it as if there is no answer that solves this plus it's an user error. Truly upto you :-)